# How can I prove that this quintic is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

How can I prove that $x^5 + 7x^4 + 2x^3 + 6x^2 - x + 8$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$? I can't use the Eisenstein's criterion and I tried to put this polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Can you give me some advice please?

Comment: Use rational root theorem to check for linear factors. If there are no linear factors, then if it can be factored, it must be factored into an irreducible quadratic and an irreducible cubic.

Comment: mod 2 it is $x(x^4+x^3+1)$ and it is not difficlut to see that $x^4+x^3+1$ if irreducible - it has no root in $\mathbb F_2$ and is not divisible by $x^2+x+1$ (the only irreducible quadratic polynomial). Since your original polynomial has no root in $\mathbb Z$ (which I didn't check, but you did, I believe), it must be irreducible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducing your polynomial modulo $2$ shows that it factors as
$$x^5+x^4+x\equiv x(x^4+x^3+1)\pmod{2}^.$$
You can check that $x^4+x^3+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_2$. So if your polynomial were reducible in $\Bbb{Q}$, then it should have an irreducible factor of degree $4$. But then it also has a linear factor, and hence a root in $\Bbb{Q}$. By the rational root theorem, this root must be in 
$$\{-8,-4,-2,-1,1,2,4,8\}.$$
Plugging all these values in shows that they are *not* roots of your polynomial, so it is *not* reducible.

Comment: i don't understand why "then it should have an irreducible factor of degree $4$. But then it also has a linear factor, and hence a root in $\mathbb{Q}$."

Comment: If your polynomial $p$ were reducible and its irreducible factors were all of degree less than $4$, then reducing this factorization modulo $2$ would give a factorization with all factors of degree less than $4$. But the factorization $x(x^4+x^3+1)$ shows that this is impossible.

Comment: so if i have a factorization in $Z_p$, i must have the same factorization if this exists in $\mathbb{Q}$? @Servaes

Comment: No. If you have a factorization in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ into factors of degrees $d_1,\ldots,d_k$, then it factors in $\Bbb{Q}$ into factors whose degrees are sums of the $d_i$, possibly $d_1+\ldots+d_k$ if it is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[X]$.

It is perhaps easier to think about the other direction; if a polynomial factors in $\Bbb{Z}$ into factors of degrees $d_1,\ldots,d_k$, then modulo every $p$ it factors into factors of degrees *at most* $d_1,\ldots,d_k$. This is simply because each of the irreducible factors is still a factor modulo $p$, and it might split further modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Show that it cannot be factored over $\mathbb{Z}$. From the hint of @ Element118: it's enough to show that it does not have factors of degree $2$. In fact it is  irreducible $\mod 3$, but you only need to show it does not have irreducible factors of degree $2$ mod $3$, and this you can do by a short check.

Comment: so I shoud try to find a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ like $(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(x^2+dx+e)$?

Comment: @Skills: Yes, you could try to find that and there will not be any. The other answer  seems to be a cleverer one. However, showing that is irreducible $\mod 3$ is a stronger result. In fact, there always will be some $p$  prime for which the polynomial will be irreducible $\mod p$, if it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ ( the converse is immediate). Finding rapidly one might not be easy. I found $p=3$ using some software (wolframalpha).  The next ones are $41$ and $53$.

Comment: @orangeskid It is not true that every polynomial irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}$ will also be irreducible modulo some prime $p$. Take for example $x^4+1$.

Comment: @Servaes: Yes, you are correct, I have to take that statement back, cf http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76993/polynomial-reducible-modulo-every-integer and other sources. Thanks!

Comment: @Skills: It turns out ( see the above examples) that it may happen that $f$ is irreducible while still being reducible module every integer $n$.  So the method may not work in general. An instructive error...