# If a polynomial have $n$ factors in $\mathbb{Z_p}$, does it have $n$ factors in $\mathbb{Q}$ if it is reducible?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have a question that i can't find an answer anywhere.
If I have a monic polynomial $$f=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0$$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If exists a prime $p$ such that $f$ has a factorization ,in $\mathbb{Z_p}$, $\bar{f}=f_{i_1}\cdots f_{i_j}$, where degree($f_{i_k})=i_k$, so if exist a factorization in $\mathbb{Q}$ this one must be $f=g_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_j}$ where degree($g_{i_k})=i_k$.

Example:
If i have a monic polynomial of degree $10$ that have in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ a factorization with degrees $(4,3,3)$. If this polynomial were riducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ should have a factorization with degrees $(4,3,3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

$X^2+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$ but $=(X+1)\cdot(X+1)$ in $\Bbb Z_2[X]$.
From this we get that the factorization of for example $(X^2+1)(X^9+1)$ in $\Bbb Q[X]$ does not correspond to the factorization in $\Bbb Z_2[X]$ in the way you propose.

Comment: Can you help me to understand better the first answer?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564164/how-can-i-prove-that-the-follow-polynomial-is-irreducible-in-mathbbq